# Reset indexes of a pandas dataframe to start from zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I'm slicing a dataframe with shape of `(10, 8004)` to smaller pieces with shape of (58, 10), to be able to plot them (it also needs to be transposed before plotted). `n_samples = 58`.

The problem is after slicing the index of the smaller pieces doesn't start from zero and the plots have big empty spaces. I tried to reset the index using different methods but all of them failed. Can someone help me to find the correct way of doing that?

Here is some of I tried:

```
for i in range(0, 138):
    sliced_df = df.iloc[:, range(i*n_samples, (i+1)*n_samples)]
    if i != 0:
       sliced_df = sliced_df.rename(index=int, columns=range(0, n_samples))
    sliced_df.T.plot(kind='line', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, label='')
```

Here is tried to use `reindex_axis`

```
for i in range(0, 138):
   sliced_df = df.iloc[:, range(i*n_samples, (i+1)*n_samples)].reindex_axis(range(0,n_samples), axis=1).T
   sliced_df.plot(kind='line', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, label='')
```

Also tried `reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
for i in range(0, 138):
   sliced_df = df.iloc[:, range(i*n_samples, (i+1)*n_samples)].reset_index(drop=True).T
   sliced_df.plot(kind='line', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, label='')
```

Comment: Did you try `reset_index()` ?

Comment: Just use `reset_index(drop=True)` before plotting.

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan right, `reset_index()` resets the indexes to be from 0 to 58 as I want. But it also adds a new linear line to my plot which is the old indexed numbers! How can I remove that? I'm using it as follow: `sliced_df = df.iloc[:, range(i * n_samples, (i + 1) * n_samples)].T.reset_index()` and plotting it like: `sliced_df.plot(kind='line', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, label='')`

Comment: @coldspeed no, that didn't work. It's listed as one of my tries in the question above.

Comment: @Birish when you `reset_index()` it takes the old index and creates a column called `index`. Try `df.reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)`

Comment: thanks @VivekKalyanarangan that worked, the main issue was to transpose first and then reset indexes! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Birish I am glad it worked! Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 4]})` is the sample data i'm using.

```
df1 = df.iloc[4:8]
df1.index = np.arange(len(df1))
df1
```

now, df1 should have the correct index. You need to extend this idea to your case.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was to first Transpose the sliced_df and then reset the indexes! So all these solutions worked:

`sliced_df = df.iloc[:, range(ts * n_test_samples, (ts + 1) * n_test_samples)].T.reset_index().drop(['index'], axis=1)`

or:

`sliced_df = df.iloc[:, range(ts * n_test_samples, (ts + 1) * n_test_samples)].T.reset_index(drop=True)`

or:

`sliced_df = df.iloc[:, range(ts * n_test_samples, (ts + 1) * n_test_samples)].T
sliced_df.index = np.arange(range(0,n_samples))`